# Proper way to synchronize two state machines with slightly skewed clock in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am implementing a receiver for an ADC in Verilog. One sample is obtained after each 21st clock cycle.

The receiver generates the control signals as well as a duty cycled sampling clock for the ADC. The ADC sends the data back sequentially but in order to account for delay, it also sends back a **skew matched copy** of the duty cycled sampling clock. This clock is to be used to clock in the data.

The code should work for zero delay between the two clocks as well as larger delays. (But the delay won't be larger than a few clock cycles).

I do not know the best way to do this because:

1. Synthesis prohibits that variables are written in different `always @(posedge...)` blocks with (possibly) different clocks.
2. The part that clocks in the data does not have a real clock (it is duty-cycled!) so it cannot maintain a state on its own. It somehow needs to obtain the information in which cycle it is from the controlling FSM
3. Once the sampled value has been read, it needs to be transferred back to the original, un-skewed clock domain for further processing.

This shows a minimal example of my approach:

```
// Used to synchronize state between domains
reg sync_cnv = 0; // toggled by TX side when new sampling cycle starts
reg sync_sdo = 0; // synchronized by the RX side
reg reset_rx = 0; // Notify RX side of a global reset
reg reset_rx_ack = 0; // acknowledgement thereof

reg [4:0] state = 0;
reg [4:0] nextState = 0;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset == 1) begin // global reset
        state <= 0;
        sync_cnv <= 0;
        reset_rx <= 1;
    end else begin
        state <= nextState;

        // new sampling cycle starts. Inform RX logic
        if (state == 0) begin
            sync_cnv <= ~sync_cnv;
        end
        // If RX acknowledges the reset, we can turn if off again
        if (reset_rx_ack == 1) begin
            reset_rx <= 0;
        end
    end
end

// Normally, would generate all kinds of status/control signal for the ADC here
always @(*) begin
    if (state == 20) begin
        nextState = 0;
    end else begin
        nextState = state + 1;
    end
end
```

- The state is just implemented as a 21-state counter variable `state` and `nextState`
- When state if zero, a new sampling interval begins. The receiver logic (see below) will recognize this by the fact that `sync_cnv` **changes**.
- On global reset, the FSM is brought into a known state. Furthermore, `reset_rx` is set to 1 to notify the receiver logic (see below) about the reset. It stays at 1 until it is acknowledged (`reset_rx_ack`).

The receive logic:

```
reg [14:0] counter = 0; // just for dummy data. Increments every sample interval
reg sampling_done = 0; // raised when sampling is done
reg [15:0] cbuf; // holds data during data reception

always @(posedge rxclk) begin
    if ( reset_rx == 1) begin
        reset_rx_ack <= 1;
        sync_sdo <= sync_cnv;
        counter <= 0;
    end else begin
        reset_rx_ack <= 0;

        if (sync_cnv != sync_sdo) begin
            // A new sampling interval begins

            sync_sdo <= sync_cnv;

            counter <= counter + 1;
            sampling_done <= 1;
            data <= cbuf;
        end else begin
            // normal operation
            cbuf <= counter;
            sampling_done <= 0;
        end
    end
end

// synchronize "sampling_done" back to the unskewed clock.
// if data_valid, then data can be read the next cycle of clk
always @(posedge clk) begin
    r1 <= sampling_done;    // first stage of 2-stage synchronizer
    r2 <= r1;               // second stage of 2-stage synchronizer
    r3 <= r2;               // edge detector memory
end

assign data_valid = (r2 && !r3);   // pulse on rising edge
```

This code works flawlessly in simulation (with and without skew). It also works on the FPGA *most of the time*. However, the data value after a reset is not predictable: Mostly the data starts with 0 (as expected) but sometimes with 1 and or an arbitrary number (probably from the last cycle before the reset).

Comment: Why do you need to share state between two FSMs? The sampling clock is, well, a sampling clock. You say it is "already duty-cycled", but you then use it clock a counter and various other things. This is way too complicated - start again, give us the ADC part number if you have a problem.

Comment: You are correct, it was too complicated. I started over again and got it working now. The key was not sharing state but I just clock the bits into a FIFO register and read the last 16 bits. Previously I thought I need a state because what happens if the reset happens in the middle at, say Bit 5? I thought I'd need to know when the word ends. Turns out it does not matter because the FIFO takes care of it: The (incomplete) 5 bits are just shifted out again.

Comment: that's good. As an exercise, you should try getting rid of the FIFO, which is (massive) overkill. load the incoming data into a register on `rxclk`. Now, assuming that `rxclk` is actually 1/16th frequency, use your synchro circuit (probably with 3 stages) to sample `rxclk` into the `clk` domain, and generate a 1-cycle load enable pulse for the `clk` domain. Now re-sample your sampled input data into the `clk` domain and you're done, with no FIFO.

Answer (score 1):

Using a NRZ signal between clock domains is a known method. But you do not have a real synchroniser. To safely go between clocks you need two registers and a third one for edge detection:

```
// Clock domain 1:
   nrz <= ~nrz;

// Clock domain 2:
reg nrz_meta,nrz_sync,nrz_old;
....
   nrz_meta <= nrz;
   nrz_sync <= nrz_meta; 
   // nrz_sync is the signal you can safely use!
   // Do NOT use nrz_sync ^ nrz_meta, it is not reliable!

   nrz_old <= nrz_sync; // required to 'find' an edge
   if (nrz_old ^ nrz_sync)
   begin
      // Process data 
   ....
```

On a reset you set all registers to zero. That way you do not have a 'false' sample at the start. It is simplest to have the same asynchronous reset in all clock domains. Dealing with resets in clock domains is a rather (big) subject which would take an A4 page to tersely explain. In your case nothing happens for 21 clock cycles so you are safe.

Alternative is to use a standard asynchronous FIFO to transfer data between clock domains. It is the best solution if your clocks are totally independent (that is either clock can be slower or faster then the other one)
I am sure you can find code for it on the WWW. 
An asynchronous FIFO in the other direction can be used to send control information to your ADC.

Comment: Why do you say that there isn't a "real synchro"? See the last `always`. This is a 2-stage synchro, which samples the async `sampling_done`, with logic on the output of the second stage to produce `data_valid`. Of course, `data_valid` is unused, and 2 stages isn't really enough anyway.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand your code 100% but it looks like sync_cnv is not following the rules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Despite not helping for my problem, it's still useful for my general understanding. As written in my comment above (and correctly assumed by @EML) I do not need a state in the 2nd "clock domain". I just clock the bits into a FIFO, without state. I read the FIFO when the main logic sample period is over. Then I just read out the last 16 bits.

Comment: The answer is incomplete. A proper clock domain crossing also needs constraints, as well as vendor specific attributes to make sure the synthesis tool does not destroy the CDC by optimization.